# Why do I get an old object when creating a new object using let and new in a function within a service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Alright, simple basic auth authentication service in angular2.

When a user logins first time, it works. But when he/she tries to login second time with a different account. I got double basic auth string in the request headers, it's like "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWJjMTIz,Basic RMcasd9WJjMXoPj".

This is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
private url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test';
private username: string;
private password: string;
private authenticationStatus: boolean = false;

constructor(private http: Http) { }

authentication(username: string, password: string): Promise<boolean> {

    let headers = new Headers(); // <== previous headers object with old Authorization string get back from grave.
    console.log(headers);  

    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    headers.append("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");

    return this.http.get(this.url, { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => { ...
```

This is my first try angular/typescript app. I'm confused by not getting a brand new object when I use both let and new here. Is it because headersString within the header class is static? I did look into the angular headers class api doc. I tried call `headers.delete("Authorization");` right after the `let headers = new Headers();`, The old Authorization header remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm confused by not getting a brand new object when I use both let and new here.

When you log an object the *reference* to the object is logged.

As an example:

```
let x = {};
console.log(foo);
x.foo = 'foo';
```

Now on your console if you look at x *after* you've mutated it, it will show the new stuff:

[image]

In short. Your code is correct. The console can lie to you.

Alternative answer: You are doing something that is not demonstrated in the code sample you have provided.